# How to add structured data (json-ld) to Vue?

Tags: vue.js, json-ld, structured-data

What’s the correct way to add [json-ld](https://json-ld.org/) to a vue app?

I’ve added some structured data but [Google structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) does not detect the data at my url. However, if I view the source of url and paste into the testing tool it detects my data. What am missing?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can add JSON-LD with VueJS is using `v-html` like in the example below.

You can find out more about structured data from Schema.org with VueJS in [this article.](https://medium.com/@fmoessle/json-ld-with-vue-js-72cf1ac2af66)

There is also this [plugin on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-jsonld) that can help you do this.

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    const jsonld = {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "name": "Books",
        "item": "https://example.com/books"
      }, {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "name": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "item": "https://example.com/books/the-lord-of-the-rings"
      }]
    }
    return {
      jsonld
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <script v-html="jsonld", type="application/ld+json">
</template>
```

Comment: In my opinion, if part of the data used for the JsonLd comes from an untrusted source, this is vulnerable to XSS. Just replace a value in the array by ```"</script><script>alert(" hacked");</script>"```

Comment: Vue does not allow adding `<script>`  to a template `Errors compiling template:

  Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, as they will not be parsed`